# how can i add custom post type to the front end in wordpress by using elementor?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I made a custom wordpress theme from zero and i created custom post type but i can not display custom post type in the front page by elementor .
i can make a custom page from zero and add custom post type to it without elementor but i want to learn how to add it by elementor free version to get more easiy and create my page fast .

i tried to use wpcode plugin an more than 10 plugin to convert my customcode to short code and add the short code to my page by elementor .
the code is run good but i can not edit the page by elementor later (i have error say Sorry, the content area was not found in your page.You must call 'the_content' function in the current template, in order for Elementor to work on this page ).

Answer (score 0):

Enable your cpt in this section:
Menu: Elementor -> Settings -> General -> Post Types.

Answer (score 0):

You must call 'the_content' function in the current template, in order for Elementor to work on this page", it means that Elementor is not able to find the content of your page.can happen if you are using a custom template that does not call the the_content function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).